# Browse for File in Create View MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

First off, I am a newbie, so please forgive my ignorance...

In my table, I have a column that I want to store the UNC path to a PDF file.  I would like to have a button on my view that will allow the user to browse and select the file to be associated with the record.  (Behind the scene, I will copy the file to a specified file location and rename it) I have found many examples of how to browse for the file, but I just can't figure out how to get this to work on the Create and Edit views and save the rest of the data back to the database.

On my Create view, I have modified the BeginForm as so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUploadCreate", "GL", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

For my column to store the PDF location I have:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.PDF, null, new { type="file"})
```

My controller has:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUploadCreate(HttpPostedFileBase PDF)
    {
        string path = "";
        if (PDF != null)
        {
            if (PDF.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(PDF.FileName);
                    string directory = "c:\\temp\\Accruals\\PDF";
                    path = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
                    PDF.SaveAs(path);

                }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

This is all working just fine and the file is copied to the appropriate test folder.   However, my record is never saved to the database because my actual Create post is never getting hit:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(NonProject myRecord)
    {
        try
        {
            _repository.AddNonProject(myRecord);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {

            return View();
        }
    }
```

What do I need to do?  How can I reference my NonProject object as in my Create?  Can I add something to my BeginForm to also pass this to the FileUploadCreate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the posted file as a parameter to your `Create` action method. Save both (file to disk and form values to DB)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(NonProject myRecord, HttpPostedFileBase PDF)
{
    try
    {
        //Save PDF here            
       // Save form values to dB
    }
    catch
    {
        //Log error show the view with error message
         ModelState.AddModelError("","Some error occured");
        return View(myRecord);
    }
}
```

Make sure that your form ***action*** method is set to `Create`

Comment: Ahhh. Too simple.  I just had to add the NonProject myRecord to the FileUploadCreate (since that is the one called from the BeginForm).  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should post all data to one action:

ViewModel:

```
public class NonProject 
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase PDF{get;set;}

    public string SomeOtherProperty {get;set;}
    .....
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUploadCreate", "GL", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.PDF, null, new { type="file"})

    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.SomeOtherProperty)

etc..
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUploadCreate(NonProject myRecord)
{
    string path = "";

    if (myRecord.PDF != null)
    {
        if (myRecord.PDF.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(myRecord.PDF.FileName);
                string directory = "c:\\temp\\Accruals\\PDF";
                path = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
                myRecord.PDF.SaveAs(path);

            }
    }
    try
    {
        _repository.AddNonProject(myRecord);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {

        return View();
    }


    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```